# C# - Efficient way to iterate a List and create objects

Tags: c#

I have four classes. Apple, Orange, Mango and FruitIdentifier. First 3 classes have same properties ID and Price. I have a list of objects ( contains apple, orange and mango). I am iterating the list and based on the item type, creating FruitIdentifier instances and adding to a new list.

```
 public class Apple
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }


    public class Orange
    {
       // props same as apple
    }

    public class Mango
    {
        // props same as apple
    }

    public class FruitIdentifier
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public FruitIdentifier (int id, double price, string name)
        {
            ID = id;
            Price = price;
            Name = name;

        }
    }
```

I am expecting a long list. My doubt is, before creating FruitIdentifier objects, I assign ID and Price properties to two variables and then passing those variables to FruitIdentifier constructor. Is there any performance improvement if I give the values directly inside the Constructor call.

```
List<object> fruitList = new List<object> (); // going to contains 1000s of items

            List<FruitIdentifier> fruisIdentifiers = new List<FruitIdentifier> ();

            foreach (var fruit in fruitList)
            {
                if (fruit is Apple apple)
                {
                    apple.Price += 10;

                    var id = apple.ID;
                    var price = apple.Price;

                    fruisIdentifiers.Add(new FruitIdentifier (id, price, "Apple"));
                }

                if (fruit is Orange orange)
                {

                }

                if (fruit is Mango mango)
                {

                }

            }

// fruisIdentifiers.Add(new FruitIdentifier (apple.ID, apple.Price, "Apple"));

// like this. Any perfromance improvement ?
```

Comment: Use IEnumerable or array instead List. Use for instead foreach. Avoid this kind of logic and try to work with the data you only need. Give to the database the work that belongs to database.

Comment: Use an interface `IFruit` with properties `ID` , `Name` and `Price` and let the classes implement it. Then fill a `List<IFruit>`. There's no need for that `FruitIdentifier` or this `List<object>`. If you later want all apples out of this list use `List<Apple> apples = fruits.OfType<Apple>().ToList()`

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a performance improvement between:

```
var id = apple.ID;
var price = apple.Price;

fruisIdentifiers.Add(new FruitIdentifier (id, price, "Apple"));
```

and

```
fruisIdentifiers.Add(new FruitIdentifier (apple.ID, apple.Price, "Apple"));
```

It will be so negligable as to be non-existant. Don't prematurely optimize, and when you find your program is not performing, go looking for the real issues.

Comment: I would have guessed that _maybe_ the local vars would be optimized away anyway. But really not sure about that.

Comment: @Fildor I'm almost _certain_ those local vars will be optimised away.